# Can JQuery check for the correct combination of class names eg .correct & .selected via  a button?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a basic game using jQuery where a user clicks and selects a certain combination of images and then a notification appears.

Can anyone at the very least can point me in the right direction on how to go about this as all attempts up until now have failed miserably.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
var v = $(".className").size();
```

Comment: $().size() does a call to .length anyway:

    // The number of elements contained in the matched element set
    size: function() {
        return this.length;
    },'''

Comment: .length does not have the overhead of a function call

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#gamebord img').click(function() {
   $(this).addClass('selected');
   if ($("#gamebord img.selected").length == 2)
       alert('2 images selected');
});
```

UPDATE:

```
$('#gamebord img').click(function() {
   $(this).addClass('selected');
   if ($("#gamebord img.selected.correct").length == 2)
       alert('2 images selected');
});
```

UPDATE 2:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
   if ($("#gamebord img.selected").length == 2)
       alert('2 images selected');
});
```

Comment: You can call a function from .length ?

Comment: its not a function its property

Comment: i need to check if the correct combination of elements has been selected on a button click....

Comment: Great, thanks, that seems to be functioning OK. but if I want this to be more specific, ie to check if two class names are present - .selected & .correct - then a seperate button checks for this information.

Comment: No, i think you misunderstand. A user must make their selection and click a submit button separately to check for the correct combination of class names = .correct & .selected